# group_by() and percentages: summarise() drops the columns I also need - R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have this `df`:

```
> df <- data.frame(Adults = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
+                  Children = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
+                  Teens = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
+                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
   Adults Children Teens
1       5        0     1
2       5        1     2
3       5        2     3
4       5        2     2
5       0        1     2
6       5        1     3
7       0        2     3
8       4        2     1
9       4        0     1
10      1        2     1
```

We can see that `Children` doesn't have `3,4,5` values and `Teens` doesn't have `0,4,5` values. However, we know that `Adults`, `Children`, and `Teens` could have from `0 to 5`.

When I use `group_by()` with `summarise()`, `summarise` drops the columns I'm not grouping. The code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Adults) %>% mutate(n_Adults = n()) %>%
  group_by(Teens) %>% mutate(n_Teens = n()) %>%
  group_by(Children) %>% mutate(n_Children = n())
```

And when I group by `c(0,1,2,3,4,5)` (in order to have all the possible values) it gives me this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 6
```

I'm looking for this output:

```
Values n_Adults n_Children n_Teens p_Adults p_Children p_Teens
     0        2          2       0      0.2        0.2     0               
     1        1          3       4      0.1        0.1     0.4                 
     2        0          5       3      0          0       0.3             
     3        0          0       3      0          0       0.3                
     4        2          0       0      0.2        0.2     0                    
     5        5          0       0      0.5        0.5     0
```

Where `n_` is the count of the respective column and `p_` is the percentage of the respective column.

Comment: you didn't provide the actual code that fails, "when I group by c(0,1,2,3,4,5) " is ambiguous, do you need `group_by_at` ?

Comment: Do you use mutate or summarize in you’re code?

Comment: I tried with both of them. I'm just trying to get the output.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper what I mean with that is: the possible values of the three columns could be any of those. However, in this example Children doesn't have 3,4 and 5. But tomorrow they could have them. So, I'm looking for an escalable solution (that's why I'm trying to group by the vector c(0,1,2,3,4,5) in order to ALWAYS count all the possible values for each column)

Comment: Why not just include the code that fails, and thus make your issue reproducible ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `gather` the data into 'long' format, get the frequency with `count` after converting the 'value' to `factor` with `levels` specified as 0:5, `spread` to 'wide' format and create the 'p' columns by dividing with the `sum` of each column and if needed change the column name (with `rename_at`)

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df) %>% 
  count(key, value = factor(value, levels  = 0:5)) %>%
  spread(key, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate_at(2:4, list(p = ~./sum(.)))%>%
  rename_at(2:4, ~ paste0(.x, "_n"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Adults = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L), Children = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Teens = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(reprex)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(20)

df <- data.frame(Adults = sample(0:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                                  Children = sample(0:2, 10, replace = TRUE),
                                  Teens = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE),
                                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#>    Adults Children Teens
#> 1       5        2     2
#> 2       4        2     1
#> 3       1        0     2
#> 4       3        2     1
#> 5       5        0     1
#> 6       5        1     1
#> 7       0        0     3
#> 8       0        0     3
#> 9       1        0     1
#> 10      2        2     3

 df_adults <- df %>%
  count(Adults) %>%
   rename( n_Adults = n)

df_childred <- df %>%
  count(Children)  %>%
  rename( n_Children = n)


df_teens <- df %>%
  count(Teens)  %>%
  rename( n_Teens = n)


df_new <- data.frame(unique_id = 0:5)


df_new <- left_join(df_new,df_adults, by = c("unique_id"="Adults"))

df_new <- left_join(df_new,df_childred, by = c("unique_id"="Children"))

df_new <- left_join(df_new,df_teens, by = c("unique_id"="Teens"))

df_new <- df_new %>%
          replace_na(list( n_Adults=0, n_Children=0, n_Teens=0))

df_new %>%
  mutate(p_Adults = n_Adults/sum(n_Adults),p_Children = n_Children/sum(n_Children), p_Teens = n_Teens/sum(n_Teens))
#>   unique_id n_Adults n_Children n_Teens p_Adults p_Children p_Teens
#> 1         0        2          5       0      0.2        0.5     0.0
#> 2         1        2          1       5      0.2        0.1     0.5
#> 3         2        1          4       2      0.1        0.4     0.2
#> 4         3        1          0       3      0.1        0.0     0.3
#> 5         4        1          0       0      0.1        0.0     0.0
#> 6         5        3          0       0      0.3        0.0     0.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>